# Java - Why doesnt the size of jpanel work

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a Frame that highlights some `JLabels` and a `JtextField`, where you can type a host name and in return get the IP address. But my UI is not working as I want it to. I want the size of the UI to be around `200,200` but when I run the program I don't have anything until I maximize and then I can see my label. Here is the code, hopefully you guys can tell me what I have done wrong.

```
public class Exercise1 extends JPanel {
    private JLabel jlblIP = new JLabel("IP= 221.1231.231");
    private JLabel jlblName = new JLabel("Namn = DAMSKDLASM");
    private JLabel jlblHostIP = new JLabel("Host ip --------");
    private JLabel jlblHostName = new JLabel("Host name:");
    private JTextField jtxtfield = new JTextField("");
    private InetAddress ipaddress;

    public Exercise1(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        add(jlblIP);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exercise1 mainjpn = new Exercise1();
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.getContentPane();
        jframe.pack();
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(jframe.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.add(mainjpn);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to work with UI components on the main thread...

Comment: Why are you calling jframe.getContentPane() and ignoring the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your Exercise1 JPanel to the JFrame's content pane instead.

Also, don't forget to [ensure that any code that touches your UI is done from the event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Something like:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Exercise1 extends JPanel {
    private JLabel jlblIP = new JLabel("IP= 221.1231.231");
    private JLabel jlblName = new JLabel("Namn = DAMSKDLASM");
    private JLabel jlblHostIP = new JLabel("Host ip --------");
    private JLabel jlblHostName = new JLabel("Host name:");
    private JTextField jtxtfield = new JTextField("");
    private InetAddress ipaddress;

    public Exercise1(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        add(jlblIP);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exercise1 mainjpn = new Exercise1();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
                jframe.getContentPane().add(mainjpn);
                jframe.pack();
                jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(jframe.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                jframe.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Micheal! But why should every code that touches my Ui be done from the Swing Thread if you dont mind me asking :)

Comment: Swing programs use an event dispatch thread to carry out executing code that interacts with Swing components.  It was a design choice when Swing was created that the only thread that can safely interact with Swing components is the event dispatch thread.  SwingUtilities is a helper class provided to let you post Runnables to be executed on the event dispatch thread.  If you don't do this, your app can misbehave (lock up, for example) in unpredictable ways.

Answer (score 2):

jframe.add(mainjpn) should be placed before pack() and setVisible()

Comment: Thank you very much! ps. why shouldnt i be working with UI components on the main thread?

Comment: Swing uses a single threaded UI model.  As such it is not thread-safe to create, modify or query Swing components from a thread other than the event-dispatching thread.